# Dynamically set choices in django model based on whether adding a new record or editing existing

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to have one set of choices if adding a new record and a different set if editing an existing record. I thought something like the following would work but it doesn't.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (('1', 'Option 1'), ('2', 'Option 2'), ('3', 'Option 3'), ('4', 'Option 4'),)
    def test(self):
        if self.pk:
            return True
    if test is True:
        CHOICES = (('1', 'Option 1'), ('2', 'Option 2'),)
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)
```

Comment: do you want to achieve this for the Django Admin, or just to display in a django form?

Comment: For the Django admin

Comment: your `boolean` is not right, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your code is good enough to do the trick you're trying to;
Just a little mistake here:
`if test is True:` **#NOT GOOD**
instead it should be:
 `if test:` **#GOOD**

Your code would become

```
if test: # the opposite is : if not test:
    CHOICES = (('1', 'Option 1'), ('2', 'Option 2'),)
```